# How can I remove this big blank space?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

This Blank Space keep appearing on Internet Explorer 11 when I am scrolling down. Though it doesn't appear nor on Chrome nor when I tried to modify the page.

Can someone help me on this one ?

[image: My image]

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: did you inspect the element to get which element is causing this white space?

Comment: It's my Text Editor where I put my HTML and Style.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know the exact cause of the problem but setting `viewport` may solve your problem.

If this is a custom page then just add following tag in the `<head>` section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

If you are not aware for what this `viewport` is used, then you can refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) and [this](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-meta-name-viewport-content-widthdevicewidth-initialscale10).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will definitely try it ! The thing is that all is working right on Chrome. Even my Display:Flex. I tried it on Explorer before adding it to the SharePoint and all was working, in the SharePoint it doesn't.  Here's what it should look when I display on Chrome http://i.imgur.com/AGRVb6R.png

Comment: Just tried it and nothing change about it. It work for once this morning and now it's not.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that adding a `<br>` before all my HTML to separate style and HTML resolve it all. Someone know why ?

Comment: Can you please post some relevant code here..